# SQLite / Selecting rows from table WHERE column = ANYTHING

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, select, android-sqlite

In Android SQLite, I have a table: `TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL`

```
Loan_No text primary key,
agreement_date date,
branch_name text,
loan_status text,
address1 text,
address2 text,
status_type integer,
user_id integer
```

and consider the following SQLite query:

```
"SELECT COUNT(Loan_No) FROM " + TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL + " WHERE user_id = \"" + user_id + "\" AND Loan_No = \"" + Loan_No + "\" AND status_type = " + status_type
```

When I want that `status_type` variable = ANYTHING, I can simply call:

```
"SELECT COUNT(Loan_No) FROM " + TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL + " WHERE user_id = \"" + user_id + "\" AND Loan_No = \"" + Loan_No + "\""
```

but that since I am passing values to `status_type` variable from a Java function call, I cannot simply drop off that column just like that.

So that, what is the most efficient way to pass value to `status_type` variable from a Java function call, when I want that `status_type` variable = ANYTHING?

For example, that

```
"SELECT COUNT(Loan_No) FROM " + TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL + " WHERE user_id = \"" + user_id + "\" AND Loan_No = \"" + Loan_No + "\" AND status_type = *"
```

does not work out at all.

I have searched out in Stack Overflow already for its most relevant enough solution, most appropriately enough already:

I got something like, such as those like:

```
"SELECT COUNT(Loan_No) FROM " + TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL + " WHERE user_id = \"" + user_id + "\" AND Loan_No = \"" + Loan_No + "\" AND status_type = status_type"
```

but that is there any specific enough solution to this question in order to deal with it up?

I agree that `"status_type = status_type"` will always return `1` already whenever it is any given variable, but that will it also do so the same whenever that they are already any given two different enough values of same column?

Comment: am I right that you want to select where status_type is not null?

Comment: Yes, that you can answer how to do it whenever that `status_type` variable is not null also. In my real case, `status_type` variable can take from among 1 of 3 different values, -1 for Pending fragment, 1 for Planned fragment and 3 for Completed fragment. For All fragment, status_type can be anything from among the 3 different values I had mentioned above.

Comment: I can be able to do `"SELECT COUNT(Loan_No) FROM " + TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL + " WHERE user_id = \"" + user_id + "\" AND Loan_No = \"" + Loan_No + "\" AND (status_type = -1 OR status_type = 1 OR status_type = 3)"` too. But that whatever about the case whenever that there are a lots of different choices for all of possible values of `status_type` or there are infinitely many of them?

Comment: you can actually check for `AND status_type NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to do both types of queries with the same SQL command text then you could use a query like this:

```java
String sql = 
          "SELECT COUNT(Loan_No) FROM TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL "
        + "WHERE user_id = ? "
        + "    AND (1 = ? OR status_type = ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Then, to match a specific status_type you could use

```java
// query for user_id = 1 and a specific status_type
ps.setInt(1, 1);  // user_id = 1
ps.setInt(2, 0);  // 0 means "specific status_type"
ps.setInt(3, 2);  // status_type = 2
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

and for a query that matches any value of status_type you could use

```java
// query for user_id = 1 and any status_type
ps.setInt(1, 1);  // user_id = 1
ps.setInt(2, 1);  // 1 means "any status_type"
ps.setInt(3, 0);  // (this parameter is ignored)
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: It is true that if `"status_type = status_type"` does not work out at all for some reason, unlike that `"1 = 1"`, then doing so with `"1 = ? OR status_type = ?"` is a good idea, similarly to that of SQLite code injection. It takes that with 2 arguments, rather than instead of 1 argument, but that whenever that we want that `status_type` variable = some specific value then we can be able to pass as follows as like, such as those like: `"1 = 0 OR status_type = ?"`, with some specific given value for `status_type` variable: ?.

Comment: On the other hand, that whenever that we want that `status_type` variable = anything then we can be able to pass as follows as like, such as those like: `"1 = 1 OR status_type = ?"`, with any given value for `status_type` variable: ?.

Comment: By the way, that I am not doing so with INSERT or UPDATE statements on SQLite queries in order to be able to do so with `ps.setInt(1, 1); // user_id = 1`, `ps.setInt(2, 0); // 0 means "specific status_type"` and `ps.setInt(3, 2); // status_type = 2`. Or `ps.setInt(1, 1); // user_id = 1`, `ps.setInt(2, 1); // 1 means "any status_type"` and `ps.setInt(3, 0); // (this parameter is ignored)`. I am passing values to different variables available from possible Java function, so values to ? variables can be passed on from SQLite query by making use of simply in just one single line of SQLite query.

Comment: It is true that if `"status_type = status_type"` does not work out at all for some reason, unlike that `"1 = 1"`, then will it not do so with ever?

Answer (score 2):

If you wan to take all the status_type it is no need to specify it on the query.

The query will be

"SELECT COUNT(Loan_No) FROM " + TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL + " WHERE user_id = \"" + user_id + "\" AND Loan_No = \"" + Loan_No

Comment: I already mentioned that I am passing the value to the `status_type` variable from a Java function, so that this solution does not work out at all.

Comment: By making use of the different tools and then techniques. Or - or by making use of the same or - or and then different way and then method - technique vs versus tool. Or appropriate messages to players must and then should be posted at appropriate games only - play moves of games - or each and then every - with to - enough only - with to - enough only. Or and then by making use of the same and then different or way and then method - or tool and then technique, or...

Comment: Or appropriate messages to players must and then should be posted at appropriate games only - play moves of games - or each and then every - with to - enough only - with to - enough only. That ever, which ever, a way, a way.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps consider using something along the lines of :-

```
public String buildGetLoadCountSQL(Integer userid, String loan_no, Integer status_type) {

    String whereclause = "";
    if(userid != null) {
        whereclause = whereclause + " user_id=" + String.valueOf(userid);
    }
    if (loan_no != null && loan_no.length() > 0) {
        if (whereclause.length() > 0) {
            whereclause = whereclause + " AND ";
        }
        whereclause = whereclause + " Loan_No=?'" + loan_no + "' ";
    }
    if (status_type != null) {
        if (whereclause.length() > 0) {
            whereclause = whereclause + " AND ";
        }
        whereclause = whereclause + " status_type=" + String.valueOf(status_type);
    }
    if (whereclause.length() > 1) {
        whereclause = " WHERE " + whereclause;
    }
    return "SELECT COUNT(Loan_No) FROM " + TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL + whereclause;
}
```

With this you can omit any of the values by specifying null in it's place.

For example

```
    buildGetLoadCountSQL(null,null,null);
```

returns (all rows) :-

```
    SELECT COUNT(Loan_No) FROM your_table
```

and

```
    buildGetLoadCountSQL(10,"0123456789",10);
```

returns (most selective) :-

```
    SELECT COUNT(Loan_No) FROM your_table WHERE userid=10 AND Loan_No= '0123456789' AND status_type=10
```

and

```
    buildGetLoadCountSQL(10,"0123456789",null);
```

***returns (what you want from your question) :-***

```
    SELECT COUNT(Loan_No) FROM your_table WHERE userid=10 AND Loan_No= '0123456789'
```

- **Note** this is in-principle code and has not been tested so it may contain minor errors.

Comment: If you made the code more complex like this, with types of multiple 'if' clauses, then will it not have a type of impact on the efficiency of the mobile application? Is there not any other type of way available as a type of alternative solution available to do entire thing you had mentioned above simply in just one single line of SQLite query? By the way that the type of impact on efficiency only needs to be measured for my other type of asked question of mine along with this type of question after all, and not for this type of question at all.

Comment: The biggest impact on the efficiency is design not the odd if statement needed to compensate for poor design , which of course would be required, as such, in any SQL statement.